# Calculating the line integral of a curve given line segments

Tags: integration, line-integrals

**I have the curve and I wish to integrate the curve: (x^2 dx + y^2 dy + z^2 dz).**

Notation wise: A "C" as in to displace the bottom limit of an integral (I will attach an image so that it is easier to visualise).

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eERo.jpg

**And the aforementioned curve consists of the line segments from (zero,one,zero) to (one,zero,one) and then from (one,zero,one) to (two,one,three).**

I anticipate that there will be a kink/sharp twist in said curve.

With the boldened information being the most relevant - how would I solve this integral.

So far I have got this:

x=xA+t(xB−xA)  dx=(xB-xA)dt.

y=yA+t(yB−yA)  dy=(yB-yA)dt
z=zA+t(zB−zA) dz=(zB-zA)dt.

so

$(ds)2=(dx)2+(dy)2+(dz)2$

$$ds=||\vec{AB}||dt$$

[Although I express doubt and skepticism whether this is right.]

Thank you for any help/assistance given.

**Note: The image probably surmises the gist of my question a lot better.**

-Nomad609

Comment: Your $dx$should be $dx=(x_b-x_a)dt$ .

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Hello again, thank you. This question is loosely based on the previous question you helped me with, can I ask how you know how to form the parametric equations please.

Comment: I made some corrections in text of Your question.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam  Thanks for the assistance

Comment: bump (bump up this post)

Comment: Is it ok now with segments.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam thank you but I am still stuck :(

Comment: For example take $A(0,2,3), B(3,6,3)$ and try to find $ds$ along the $[A,B]$ segment.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam hey, can I ask why should we take that - do we not consider the first then the second parts separately. Where does the 6 come from? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Of which $6$ do you think.

Comment: Hey Abdallah I have attempted this questions further and I am stuck at this point, please can you take a look at it

Comment: in your formula, replace $x_A by 0$, $y_A by 2$, $z_A by 3$, $x_B by 6$ ,$ z_B by 3$ and compute $ds$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam hey, this is what I have done so far, could you please take a look at it?  http://imgur.com/a/s8VIo

Comment: my teacher said that the answer is 35/3 :O

Comment: Is it Ok now. it's $34$ not $35$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for the second question.

The parametric equations of the segment $[A(0,1,0),B(1,0,1)]$ are

$x=0+t(1-0)=t$

$y=1+t(0-1)=1-t$

$z=0+t(1-0)=t$

thus

$x^2=z^2=t^2$ ,$y^2=1+t^2-2t$

$dx=-dy=dz=dt$

if we replace in the integral, we get

$$\int_0^1(t^2-(1+t^2-2t)+t^2)dt=\frac{1}{3}.$$

For the other segment, we have

$x=1+t, \; y=t, \; z=1+2t$

$dx=dy=dt, \; dz=2dt$

if we replace, we find

$$\int_0^1(10t^2+10t+3)dt=\frac{34}{3}.$$

Comment: Thank you Abdallah, this is very correct :)

Comment: @nomad609 Ok friend of the world.

Comment: Yo, in the similar other thread I posted those users said the answer is 35/3 when you add the two separate areas together. Do we by convention leave the answer as you have done or add them together do you know :)  p.s. are you egyptian/moroccan :)

Comment: @nomad609 Yes, the integral from A to C is the sum of integrals from A to B and from B to C. Hello from Morocco.

Comment: Thank you so much. Very nice. Marrakesh is very nice place. Regards from West Coast :)

Comment: @nomad609 Thanks. Best wishes.